# React Native Panresponder issue after retouching and moving the image return back to initial position

Tags: react-native, expo

I have one draggable car image if i dragging the car first time it works fine after second time re dragging the car image return back to the initial position. I want to drag an image smooth and draggable with finger touch. please help me

import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View, Text, PanResponder, Animated, Easing, Dimensions, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
    import { ToastAndroid } from 'react-native';

```
export default class Viewport extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      disableCar: false,
      dropZoneCar: null,
      panCar: new Animated.ValueXY(),
    };
    this.carFunction();
  }

  carFunction = () => {
    this.panResponderCar = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event([null, {
        dx: this.state.panCar.x,
        dy: this.state.panCar.y
      }]),
      onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
        console.log(evt)
      },

      onPanResponderRelease: (e, gesture) => {
        // console.log(e)

        if (this.isDropZoneCar(gesture)) {
          ToastAndroid.show('Correct', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        } else {
          ToastAndroid.show('Wrong', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  isDropZoneCar(gesture) {
    var dz = this.state.dropZoneCar;
    return gesture.moveY > dz.y && gesture.moveY < dz.y + dz.height;
  }

  setDropZoneCar(event) {
    this.setState({
      dropZoneCar: event.nativeEvent.layout
    });
  }
  setDropZoneBike(event) {
    this.setState({
      dropZoneBike: event.nativeEvent.layout
    });
  }
  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', }}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View
              onLayout={this.setDropZoneCar.bind(this)}
              style={[styles.dropZone, { backgroundColor: this.state.disableCar ? 'green' : '#2c3e50' }]}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Drop a Car</Text>
            </View>
            <View
              onLayout={this.setDropZoneBike.bind(this)}
              style={[styles.dropZone, { backgroundColor: this.state.disableCar ? 'green' : '#2c3e50' }]}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Drop a Bike</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {this.draggableCar()}
          </View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  draggableCar() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.draggableContainer} >
        <Animated.View
          {...this.panResponderCar.panHandlers}
          style={[this.state.panCar.getLayout()]}>
          <Image
            style={{ position: "absolute", width: 200, height: 100, right: 10, top: 300, }}
            source={require('./assets/carr.png')}
          />
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let CIRCLE_RADIUS = 36;
let Window = Dimensions.get('window');
let styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1
  },
  dropZone: {
    height: 100,
    backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
    marginTop: 100
  },
  text: {
    marginTop: 25,
    marginLeft: 5,
    marginRight: 5,
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#fff'
  },
  draggableContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: Window.height / 2 - CIRCLE_RADIUS,
    left: Window.width / 2 - CIRCLE_RADIUS,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening to the delta of the finger movement `dx` and `dy`, so whenever you touch again, your pan values drop to `0`'s. You should set an offset on your pan values every time you touch to fix this. Add this piece of code:

```
onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
  this.state.panCar.setOffset({x: this.state.panCar.x._value, y: this.state.panCar.y._value});
  this.state.panCar.setValue({x: 0, y: 0});
}
```

This will set the offset for your pan to current position, so it doesn't jump back after consequent touches. Hope this helps.

Comment: this.state.panBike.setOffset(this.state.panBike.__getValue());
        this.state.panBike.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
this is correct

Comment: Yes, that can work, but be careful with ._getValue() and ._value. If you decide to useNativeDriver in your animations in the future, that value won't change. You might want to look into .addListener() function on the Animated.Value. Something like panCar.x.addListener(({value}) => this._xValue = value) and use _xValue and _yValue to set the offset.

Comment: I have another doubt how to set Animated.spring default initial value?

Comment: I'm afraid, I don't understand the question. Animated.spring just drives an Animated.Value, which already has an initial value that you create it with. You can specify how "bouncy" the spring animation is, but I'm not sure what you mean by default value.